# [Postgres][Doctrine][Symfony 3] boolean and nullable issue

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm stuck with the following problem :
I'm setting a new boolean parameter into my entity,

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $tester = false;
```

here, the tester has to be set to false,
but I get the following error when I try the -f :

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERREUR:   « tester » column got NULL values

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: have you got value in your database yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi The New boolean field can't be null so you have to make a default value true or false 
so change your code to

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false,options={"default":false})
 */
  private $tester;
```

Comment: this is what he did with the `private $tester = false;`

Comment: he has the problem when he update database shema because that field is not null so he need to make a default value in the ORM but what he did its just add default value when he add new row to the the table it's like a __construct

Comment: or maybe this is because he already has datas in the DB that are null, this is why i asked him the question but he didn't responded, so we can't know

Comment: the default : false is good. I added it and it worked. I also let the $tester = false in place, so I won't face the null violation issue anymore. 
 thanks you guys  for your help!